# vim cannot open absolute directories from command line

Tags: command-line, vim

Running vim 7.3 on CentOS 5. Cannot open directories from command line, except ".", so this does not work (vim opens, but just shows a blank buffer):

```
$ /usr/bin/vim /tmp
```

But this works fine, giving the NetRW display of the directory, from which I can choose files, etc.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ /usr/bin/vim .
```

This also works fine

```
$ cd $HOME
$ /usr/bin/vim ../../tmp
```

Inreasing verbosity does not help much:

```
$  /usr/bin/vim -V99absolute.log /tmp
$ head -n3 absolute.log

chdir()
fchdir() to previous dir
$  /usr/bin/vim -V99relative.log ../../tmp
$ head -n3 relative.log

chdir(../..)
fchdir() to previous dir
```

And subsequent differences between the 2 logs seem to be related to that initial different chdir() call.

Editting files works fine, both absolutely and relatively, but logging them verbosely gives more weight to the theory that the initial chdir() call is the problem, because it now contains a directory in both cases:

```
$ vim -V99abso-fred.log /tmp/fred.log
$ vim -V99rela-fred.log ../../tmp/fred.log
$ head -n3 abso-fred.log

chdir(/tmp)
fchdir() to previous dir
$ head -n3 rela-fred.log

chdir(../../tmp)
fchdir() to previous dir
```

Any suggestions as to how to track down the difference in that initial chdir() call? Where's it coming from? How to ask vim to show files it is sourcing as well as commands?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the [latest development version](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#NETRW) of the _netrw_ plugin? Also, you should direct issues with the plugin to the author.

Comment: @IngoKarkat - Upgrading to the latest version of netrw makes no difference. Why do you think the issue is with that plugin? The log files start diverging at line 2, whereas the netrw scripts are not brought in by vim till line 300+. So I doubt it could be responsible

Comment: I suggest temporarily reducing your .vimrc to a bare minimum and moving all other plugins aside to see if it still happens.